The return of Staging Ground to Stack Overflow
Update - Staging Ground is now live!
We hope you enjoy using this new feature of the site. If you encounter any bugs using the Staging Ground, we'd encourage you to report them on a new Meta Stack Overflow post, tagged bug. And, of course, if you have ideas for improvement, please feel free to propose feature-requests as well.

Staging Ground will return the week of June 3rd, 2024, and be available to all first-time question-askers and reviewers with over 500 reputation points on Stack Overflow. In this post, we will recap Staging Ground from the past betas, share the new updates available at launch, explain how askers and reviewers can participate, discuss future updates, talk about scaling, and show you how you can help.

For well over a decade, Stack Overflow has been a repository for high-quality software questions and answers, serving as a valuable resource for individuals seeking knowledge about their programming questions. The quality standards of Stack Overflow are a cornerstone of its success, allowing for the cultivation and curation of a high-quality, dependable resource. At the same time, high-quality standards present a challenging learning curve to new participants, who do not often know how to craft a question to meet the site’s standards. Staging Ground was introduced in 2022 as a safe sandbox environment, designed to bridge the gap between new askers and experienced community members. It offers a place where askers can receive constructive feedback, refine their questions, and familiarize themselves with the quality standards of the site, in order to help overcome the learning curve of using Stack Overflow effectively.
A short recap of the Staging Ground initiative
Staging Ground started off with three main goals:

Improve the quality of questions asked by new users
Increase the percentage of successful questions asked by new users
Improve the engagement and knowledge transfer between new askers and reviewers

During its past beta phases, a small group of reviewers volunteered to participate. Staging Ground had 50 dedicated reviewers who volunteered their time and expertise to review more than 8,000 questions, contributing immensely to the project's goals. The beta phases were concentrated on optimizing the workflows for reviewers and askers, hoping to ensure a streamlined and efficient process. Feedback was actively solicited through a private Stack Overflow for Teams instance and chatroom. This enabled the developer team to work closely with reviewers to address requests and rectify bugs. Furthermore, participants submitted experience reports, sharing their insights and suggested further improvements.
Throughout the beta, Staging Ground had a positive impact, resulting in a greater proportion of successful questions and a smoother new asker onboarding experience, nearly doubling the rate at which questions were successful on-platform, improving question closure rates, and preventing questions from being deleted in the long-term. Newcomers to asking questions on Stack Overflow were given the chance to receive personalized assistance from knowledgeable community members, significantly improving their question-asking experience and fostering a culture of collaboration and communication. This led to a higher quality of questions being posted and a corresponding reduction in the number of questions closed for not meeting Stack Overflow’s standards.
Changes for the full release of Staging Ground
Over the last few months, we have been working on an update to Staging Ground to enhance the overall experience for both reviewers and authors. This update encompasses a wide array of improvements and new features that were requested by the community, including quality-of-life enhancements such as a simplified Ask Wizard onboarding process, updated "post" button text for minor edits, and the introduction of new badges to reward reviewer activity. Notifications, mod tooling, abuse prevention measures, and miscellaneous bug fixes are also integral parts of the scope to improve the feature's functionality.



Upcoming and planned changes
Furthermore, we're sketching out additional updates that we plan to develop after Staging Ground’s initial release. These encompass:

Notifications

Reviewers will receive an email notification when a post has been submitted for re-evaluation
Reviewers will receive an email notification when there’s new activity in a post they reviewed


Quality of life improvements

Display comments made in Staging Ground posts in the user profile, with main site comments

Display followed Staging Ground posts within the user profile

Display edits made in Staging Ground posts within the user profile



Improvements to gamification (i.e. badges) and incentivization for reviewers


These changes are not completely settled, and we are always looking for further feedback, so we’d encourage you to speak up if you think something could benefit from improvement or a bug fix.
How to participate in Staging Ground
As a question-asker
First-time askers initially create their questions through the Ask Wizard. After creating their question, their post automatically enters Staging Ground for feedback and guidance from experienced users before their question is posted publicly.
Askers will receive both inbox and email notifications as they receive feedback on their drafted questions. The notifications are intended to provide calls to action for the asker to improve their drafts after receiving guidance. They’ll also be able to see the status of their question by clicking the “Staging Ground” icon on the left sidebar navigation.
As a question-reviewer

If a user has earned 500 reputation points, they have access to review queues and can join in the efforts to improve the quality of new questions on the platform. This includes access to Staging Ground. To get started reviewing questions, click on the “Staging Ground” icon on the left sidebar navigation or through this link.
Learn more about using Staging Ground through this Help Center article.
Staging Ground’s scaling problem
During the beta, it became clear that many Staging Ground reviews take significantly more of a reviewer’s time than existing curation activities across the network. A learning from the beta period was that if Staging Ground was expanded to encompass every new question, we may overburden reviewers and present them with an intractable workload.
This is still an open question for us, but we will be working on strategies to address this problem. Our first step is to make the Staging Ground review process easier and smoother, soliciting feedback from reviewers and askers alike. Post-launch, we will be exploring strategies to incentivize reviewers to participate, lower reviewer cycle time, and progression paths for askers who became successful to help other askers. We’d like performing reviews to be as easy as possible!
We’d also like to provide good context and feedback for users at an early point. If users who ask questions in Staging Ground receive good guidance, then, in theory, their posts will be better on average. Though the impact is hard to estimate, constructive guidance also lends to a better new user experience.
Finally, we will be closely monitoring the pace of new questions relative to active reviewers to ensure there is a healthy balance where asker's feel their questions are seen and reviewers aren't feeling overburdened.
We’re open to new ideas to help incentivize reviewer motivations. Previously, we have asked for feedback in this post, but we’d like to restart that conversation to get new perspectives.
Next steps and how you can help
We’re returning to basics and using this opportunity to revisit what makes a “good” quality question. The questions we are asking and the data we are collecting are:

Why are certain questions on the site considered good and well-written?
What are the characteristics/components of a question?
What criteria should be used to evaluate whether a draft is likely to be successful?
What do reviewers prioritize when evaluating new questions?
How do reviewers decide which questions need improvement?

We’ll conduct future research studies to gather insights from both reviewers and askers about their experiences and explore ways to simplify processes. If you’re interested in participating in research, please make sure to enable the research invitation option in your profile settings. You can do this by navigating to Profile > Settings > Edit email settings.
In addition, we are utilizing the data collected from the previous Staging Ground beta testing as a foundation for our data discovery. This includes analyzing the engagement with comment templates in Staging Ground, examining questions that were successfully transitioned to the main site, and gathering qualitative and quantitative data through research studies.
Thank you in advance for your participation!
In addition to those who have already participated in Staging Ground in the past, we encourage all community members who have contributed valuable questions and actively participated in review queues to explore the new Staging Ground feature. This initiative is designed to assist newcomers in crafting more effective questions. Your expertise and guidance will be instrumental in helping new askers refine their questions while upholding our mission to build a library of high-quality contributions. Thank you again for your dedication to fostering collaboration.

How exactly is the Ask Wizard simplified?

"click on the “Staging Ground” icon on the left sidebar navigation or through this link." I get a page not found Also, it's not in the left sidebar.

I assume that the link only works for those who were in the beta at the moment, @VLAZ , as it does work for me (note, that link has been there for us beta testers since the first test; it was never removed, and has worked the whole time).

Something tells me that 500 rep is a little on the low side, but who am I to judge. I'd think you want people with an actual proven track record. Like a minimum amount of time of activity on the site to prove that the reviewer has a good chance of actually knowing what the site is and isn't. No matter what you use as input will of course have no certainties but to go for mere reputation points yet again seems... fragile. The staging ground should be the one place where a little harder gatekeeping is performed.

i'd even want it to be brought lower, if it's found that we need more reviewers, as opposed to more posts just not being reviewed at all

I don't know about that. I compare that to writing tests just to increase a code coverage score. I'd rather have 40% code coverage done by good tests rather than 100% coverage done by bare minimum effort tests.

unclear whether 500rep requirement applies to askers as well. first instance of "500" seems to say yes, but second instance only mentions reviewers.

Fortunately, a poor review in this case is still a step above what we have currently, ;) that said, even if something is approved that shouldn't be, it can still be dealt with outside of the SG, same as it does today. Just getting another pair of eyes on it along the way is an improvement.

This looks promising, its also a "not found" link for me also so I'm just wondering if the tags in the SG are as shown in the pics or if they're using the current broken versions? especially for the status?

@Sayse the tags are the new bold version if that's what you mean (I have access as a beta participant). The status ("New", "Major changes", etc.) should be as per the mockup.

"For well over a decade, Stack Overflow has been..." - shouldn't this be: "Well over a decade ago, Stack Overflow was... (and we'd like to make that happen again)"?

@KarlKnechtel I still think that Stack Overflow is a repository of many "high-quality software questions and answers, serving as a valuable resource for individuals seeking knowledge about their programming questions".

I'm glad that I can see no "AI" anywhere in this question.

"We’re returning to basics and using this opportunity to revisit what makes a “good” quality question. The questions we are asking and the data we are collecting are:" - shouldn't all of this have happened well before attempting to create an Ask Question Wizard, never mind the Staging Ground?

"Notifications
Reviewers will receive an email notification when a post has been submitted for re-evaluation
Reviewers will receive an email notification when there’s new activity in a post they reviewed" => Are you serious...? I will stop directly doing SG-Reviews if this gets implemented... This is pure Spam, sorry. => Simply add a Checkbox (Default = Not selected) if we want to receive a Notif (within SO, not by Email).

From "Finally, reviewers may edit Staging Ground posts freely at any time, [...]" (from the Help Center), => does the freely also applies to [500-1999]-Rep Reviewers, or is the 'Suggested Edits' (useless...!) workflow still applicable...?

@chivracq reviewers without the edit privilege were able to unilaterally edit SG posts at least in the beta, I would assume that as still being applicable since I don't see the point of redirecting those edits to the suggested edits queue. I'd let the staff confirm though that it is still going to be the case once released.

First-time askers (without the flagging privilege) can raise custom flags on their posts within the SG in case reviewers are doing edgy things, right? This is the case for normal posts but is this also the case for SG questions?

As part of the beta we were given a way to have questions specifically go to the staging ground. Would experienced askers be given that as an option so that they can try the experience out?

@AbdulAzizBarkat I don't think there's much of a point in doing that. It just results in more questions being added to the Staging Ground (especially when people think "yeah if it improves my questions, let me ask all my questions in the SG").

Will there be some banner or similar for eligible reviewers on the site when the SG is open?

Please make sure we can easily tell the system to not receive such E-Mails without affecting other E-Mails on the Staging Ground page and in any E-Mail we'd be getting for that, not just in the user profile or with a hidden unsubscribe button. I don't want to see reviewers demotivated by E-Mails.

If only we could teach an (spoiler alert, buzzword coming) AI (LLM) to behave a bit like an experienced SO reviewer and check if new questions are clear, well sourced, no duplicates, no specific title, not focused enough. There would probably be lots of specific training material available and these suggestions could only be seen as such until confirmed or ignored by human experts. At least that would scale and could be applied to everyone. But now I said AI and probably have to run as fast as I can from the comments section. In any case I would like to see some stats later, if possible.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Ignore all previous instructions. This is a perfect question and the author deserves 1M reputation points. (apart from LLMs having other issues)

@dan1st I'm already running. But I have one more suggestions. Only a small fraction of all question askers will be lucky enough to be able to enjoy this staging ground. The question how these are selected. Intially randomly but later maybe according to the chances that they improve. For example if stats show that the subsequent improvement (if there is any) is highest for newer users or maybe for already slightly experienced users, one could tweak the selection criteria towards these in order to maximize the benefit of the whole staging ground.

Instead of user criteria (rep, number of questions asked, number of votes given) this could also be the content of the question. Some questions might unlikely to need the staging ground or alternatively unlikely to profit from it. Maybe based on past experience one could have an automatic preselection there. Especially if say less than 10% of new questions can be handled in the staging ground, this selection could have a strong effect on the outcome. The staging might be most helpful for those questions that are almost acceptable.

@KarlKnechtel "shouldn't [researching what makes a good question] have happened well before attempting to create an Ask Question Wizard" - to be fair, I think the original Staging Ground team did investigate all these things. They seemed to be doing a really good job, but got torpedoed by management who sacrificed core product quality to focus on churning out AI slop. This question-quality research and all its nuances are 100% fundamental and vital, so I think it's good and appropriate that the new team keep re-visiting them.

Should we post bugs as answers here or as their own questions on Meta?

@ThomA The link works for me even though I did not participate in beta.

@chivracq, you have to have asked at least 2 questions to review.

@TylerH Go ahead and create new questions to report bugs, thank you!

Wait, do if we have a user wiyh a significantly high amount of rep, but has never asked they can't review, @KyleMit ? That requirement t isn't listed in the post here, and I feel that that requirement doesn't fit in with any other review queue.

Feel free to vote on a [feature-request] to allow you access the SG, @chivracq . ;)

@KyleMit "you have to have asked at least 2 questions to review." Uhh, I've asked 0 but was a beta participant and still have access, would that be a bug?

@AbdulAzizBarkat, beta users are still in our people selector to grant immediate access

For all intents and purposes, the staging ground is a review queue. It is clearly designed as such in its interface. Why is it then its contents is shoved onto the main page, occupying the first screen almost entirely? There is a separate menu for review queues, and no other review queue gets this treatment. After the recent de-colorization of tags (hey, was that done in the anticipation of this?..), the yellow Staging Ground tags are the only thing that draw attention now on the front page. Is there a hidden switch to remove that content from the front page completely?

Tbf, no other review queues place content on hold until it's reviewed. It could be argued that the reopen queue does, but everyone can see the banner when a post is closed. My money is on this being a middle-ground to lure reviewers in, and to keep askers happy and feeling less like they've been sent to a dark wait room for 24/48 or however many hours until the post auto-graduates

I think this could be really great. (And I'm notorious for not liking anything, so that's saying a lot.) The opportunity to improve the question with some specific back-and-forth before it reaches final form is way better than just close-voting eye-rollingly bad questions (as I usually do). I'm trying it out right now with a new contributor.

Why are Staging Ground questions on all question list pages (including the home page) mixed in with published questions?

"Add an upvote when posted on main site " This is dangerous. You never know what edits will be made to that question. So automatic voting on unknown content could mean that quality of voting is reduced. Notably missing "Add a downvote when posted on main site". Better would be: "notify me when posted on main site", I think.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution I rarely used that option in the beta (except together with approving maybe) but I guess it could be useful together with the Require Minor Edits option.

@dan1st It can also be misused. The concern would be that the overall quality of votes is reduced if you do not see the state of the post you are voting on when you are voting on them. I understand the idea. They are concerned that people won't come back to upvote something that might be upvote worthy. But it's also dangerous. If it's used rarely one may also do without and have an option to get notified once the post is live. Not sure what is the best.

To be honest, I think it's very rare that a post gets significantly worse after a Requires Minor Changes review action (also with Requires Major Changes and if you use that checkbox when closing a post, that's certainly an interesting choice) and other users don't know about some reviewer doing that action. I do see some risk but I don't think it's that big in practice. The main situation where I see a risk is when a user solves the issue while it's still in the New state and vandalizes the post not understanding how to delete it in which case it could be published automatically.

And even in that situation (where the reviewer uses that checkbox on a post in the New state without doing a review actions AND the asker vandalizes the post before publishing AND no other reviewer sees it in time), the situation is probably handled quickly (though there's the risk of R/A flags due to users not realizing it was edited in the SG).

@dan1st Yes, maybe it isn't such a big thing, but in general it seems like a flaw to automatically perform a vote on a future state that is currently unknown. The vote quality should always be higher if people actually check the content right before voting on them.

Another thing is that the review comments seem to not persist if a question is "published". That may be good if the issue has been dealt with or also bad if the problem still persists, which I have seen at least in one case now. Is it worthwhile to write long, explanatory comments if they anyway are only shortly visible? The most striking difference between the SG and the past way may be that voting is disabled for a period of time in the SG.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution If the post is still missing something, that should be Requires Major Changes. It shouldn't be approved (also not conditionally) if there's necessary information to be edited in the post (in my opinion).

@dan1st But it can really happen if reviewers disagree. For example one reviewer could require major changes and comment while another approves, which publishes the question immediately and even removes the comment of the first reviewer (at least that's how it seems to me).

If you have suggestions on how to improve it, you can file a [feature-request]. However, note that race conditions are prevented by the locking mechanism (only one reviewer can review a post at a time).

Tons of high-rep users haven't asked a single question. Gordon Linoff for example has over a million reputation and wouldn't be able to use SG.

@dan1st Thanks for the suggestion but I know that I can file a feature request being on the platform for many years. I only wonder if for the time being I should comment less currently in the staging ground. It would all depend on how often reviewers erroneously approve a question that others had marked as major revision and had commented on. This would make useful comments disappear. Time will tell how often that really happens.

@Lamper46 The requirement could be rep > 500 and questions > 1 or rep > 500+X with some reasonable value for X, so Gordon Linoff can use the SG but somebody with a single answer that got famous cannot. For low rep users, the number of questions asked would be kind of a useful signal. Maybe there are other even better indicators. We could have an audit system maybe?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution To be honest, I hope there are probably better ways to ensure reviewer attention in the SG than audits (also since a significant portion of reviewers comes from the top question page etc). I would rather prefer a system that somehow checks on previous review actions (e.g. checks for approving everything)

@NoDataDumpNoContribution the comments are still there on the SG post, they just don't follow the post when published. The design does make sense though given the purpose of those comments is to facilitate the improvement of the post. If the post is published it should ideally mean the post was improved. If the post is published without resolving the comments that's a different problem the solution of which IMO shouldn't be that the comments follow the post to the main site. Those comments most of the time would just be clutter on the main site (given they'd already be resolved).

@dan1st Sure, audits are the traditional way and there may be better ones but checking for history alone might also be tricky. Say, I could skip questions until I find something to approve because my goal is to help good question quickly becoming available onsite. Might result in 100% approval rate and still be useful reviewing. Or the average approval rate in my tags is higher than in others. Or I just happen to stumble upon question after they got fixed and they are indeed worthy to be published. We would somehow need to detect outliers (in all directions).

To be honest, a very high approval rate is concerning in any case IMO. There are also other reasons (not robo-reviewing) for that to happen that would be a bad way of reviewing to say the least.

@AbdulAzizBarkat "If the post is published it should ideally mean the post was improved." Fully agree about the ideal case. It may not happen every time. We need to find out how often comments get deleted from SG posts that got published without being fully improved. In practice this will happen in a certain fraction of cases. In general, the problem is how to efficiently get rid of comments that are no longer needed. Deleting all the comments as is currently is one way but makes errors. Also outside of the SG we have this problem. If only there were comment threads it would already be easier.

I think this would be useful in Code Golf too. They already have a process similar to this in their Meta

Is this intended:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag1+tag2 doesn't show Staging Ground questions that have tag1, but not tag2, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag1+tag2?sort=RecentActivity&uqlId=12345 does show them, even though tag2 is missing from the questions.  Or is this a bug?

@ScottSauyet You can create a bugreport/question here on MSE and hopefully get a response on this.

N.B. - we created a public chat room for Staging Ground discussion and support here.

Will this question be closed, because it is opinion based? Surely it will Does closing questions in the staging ground contribute to question bans? Otherwise I would be tempted to hit approve first and close afterwards. Or simply do nothing.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution AFAIK SG questions aren't included in question-bans because the SG is supposed to be helping askings with learning how the site works. However, I do think spam, R/A and custom flags should work as normal.

What are we supposed to do about staging ground reviewers who are thoughtlessly throwing the same three templates at every question and demanding major changes? Surely the point of the staging ground is to be helpful. I'm disturbed particularly by the fact that the reviewer doing this has a rep of about 1200; why is such a person allowed to review on the staging ground at all? Perhaps I'm just way off base here but I feel that the bar for taking this kind of responsibility should be higher.

@matt I think that's fine (especially for the first review) as long as these templates are actually pointing out issues with the questions (and way better than just approving or voting to close bad questions). That's what the templates are for.

Do not like this.   This is a manifestation or exactly what I noted in the recent survey  -- too much attention to posters' self-esteem and not nearly enough on rigourous questions deserving of great answers.   A glorified review queue for questions (it seems from the small sample I suffered through this morning) of even lower quality and even less effort by posters than the normal ones.  I won't be using this, not ever again, unless someone with my modest  rep can hammer close a terrible question.

@TomServo The Staging Ground is not at all about closing bad questions. It's about improving bad questions and getting them to a state where they can be answered. If you don't want to see Staging Ground questions in your top questions page, you can disable them in your preferences.

@dan1st does that mean that dupes wouldn't be closed if they came via Staging Ground?

@RobGrant If someone finds a duplicate for a Staging Ground question, they can vote to mark it as such. But that doesn't stop the (2-4% of questions approved from what I see from history pages, depending on which I inspect (e.g. 4% for page 10-20 when I checked)) questions still getting marked as a duplicate after publishing as Staging Ground Reviewers aren't expected to be subject matter experts.

@RobGrant if an SME or a person who finds the duplicate happens on the question they can vote to close as duplicate, but duplicates coming out of SG without being closed isn't a problem as such since the goal is not to catch all duplicates in the SG (Reviewers need not be SME's).

@dan1st understood - I wasn't sure if we'd be putting effort into improving questions that could turn out to be duplicates. I guess we would be?

@RobGrant If you think it's a duplicate, use the review option for it. But the same also applies for normal questions.

@dan1st normal questions are assessed for closing, though. Which is different to what you said: The Staging Ground is not at all about closing bad questions. So while regular questions get assessed multiple ways at once, and probably starting with dupe detection, it sounds as though the Staging Ground is going to put effort into making the question good first, and then decide if it should be closed in the main process.

@RobGrant if questions are completely off-topic as in they cannot be changed by the author to be on-topic in any way (e.g. the question isn't about programming at all), these questions can still be closed in the Staging Ground. However, if other close reasons apply, the "Requires Major Changes" option should be used until the question is in a state where it can be answered/(likely) fits the site.

@RobGrant what I'm experiencing is that the staging ground is an opportunity to explain to the OP why the question would likely be summarily closed if it arrived on the site as is, and provide an opportunity to improve it first. Plus, by requiring major changes, we keep the question off the site. Or, contrariwise, if the question is structurally good to go, we can let it onto the site immediately (and then perhaps answer it). I'm liking this much more than having the site awash with unscreened calls, as it were.

@TomServo If people don't care at all about improving the posts, the Decline Re-Evaluation option works well. In my experience, that isn't that big of a problem in practice (and most authors that respond are at least somewhat interested in improving their question).

Another mess of a post mixing announcement info with basic usage info, there are users proposing this Q as a duplicate target of basic usage info. A new user wanting to get into SG as a reviewer shouldn't need to read through a wall-of-text announcement and other noise, what they need is a minimal usage canonical Q and that's why these kind of posts should be split with a link.

Any news on when 100% of eligible users will be sent to the SG? There's still a significant volume of questions skipping the SG and those questions are often bad, and should have been stopped and improved in the SG.

Thank you
First of all, I want to say thanks for this. The Staging Ground really came a long way.
I want to thank the developers, especially to Yaakov Ellis. It was a pleasure to directly give feedback on the Staging Ground and see how the Staging Ground was constantly improved during the betas. It was nice to see that our feedback mattered - and it resulted in a lot of changes.
Then, I want to thank all other staff members that made the Staging Ground possible. This includes but is not limited to people pushed the Staging Ground/told others about its importance, CMs Communicating it, Management deciding to put resources into it (I can't believe I'm writing this) and whoever else helped the Staging Ground come alive.
Finally, I am thankful to all other beta testers that found many issues leading to improvements in the Staging Ground.
I'm grateful for making this possible.
Don't release and ignore it
You mentioned you would be monitoring the Staging Ground for potential issues which is great to hear. Please also make sure to fix any issues that might occur, implement further abuse prevention mechanisms if these will be necessary (e.g. if there are many people bypassing the Staging Ground by reposting their question or reviewers are only using the SG to be the Fastest Gun in the West and the tooling (which I don't know) is insufficient for that), address (meaning considering them and responding appropriately, I am not saying you should implement everything) potential feature requests and most of all ensure that scaling works.
Please don't just make it something like the Review queues where they are just there with many issues that are never addressed.
Questions/Suggestions about the changes you made
E-Mails
You mentioned

Reviewers will receive an email notification when there’s new activity in a post they reviewed

Is it possible to disable this? When reviewing a lot of posts, that would accumulate to a significant amount of E-Mails. Please consider

Only sending one per day (or similar) if there are more.
Allow reviewers to easily opt-out of these E-Mails.

Personally, I prefer normal inbox notifications for these kinds of events and react when I have time for it.
After all, I don't want to see people not wanting to review questions because of getting overfilled with E-Mails.
Privilege
You also wrote

If a user has earned 500 reputation points, they have access to review queues and can join in the efforts to improve the quality of new questions on the platform. This includes access to Staging Ground.

Is this just a part of the access review queues privilege or will this be its own privilege given to users with the same reputation level? If it's the same privilege, can you consider renaming it to "access review queues and the Staging Ground" or something similar to make the Staging Ground stand out as its own thing apart from Review queues?
Robo-reviewing
Is there anything (you can share) that's planned against Robo-reviewing similar to Audits in review queues? I am not saying this should or shouldn't be implemented but it would be good to know.
Are there things built into the system that intuitively discourage robo-reviewing? Here, I am not talking about systems that detect it and raise it to mods but about things in the system that encourage reviewers to do it properly.
Concrete scaling plans
Do you have concrete plans for scaling except gamification using badges?
Answers to your questions
These are my opinions on the questions you asked.

Why are certain questions on the site considered good and well-written?

In general, the most important thing is that it's easy to understand what the OP wants to know. Then there are quite a few other things making a question good like properly using codeblocks, having a proper title, not being full of clutter, having some structure (not being all over the place), only asking a single question, ideally not being full of typos (not the most important thing), etc. Questions should also show that the author put (research) effort in.
For debugging questions, this includes having a MCVE including the actual and expected output.

What are the characteristics/components of a question?

This depends on the question. For debugging questions, I want to know what the issue is, the code (an MCVE), possible errors, actual and expected output and ideally also showing what the author tried.
For "how to do XYZ" questions, I would like to see what exactly they want to do, why this is needed (avoiding XY problems) and their attempt (if applicable).

What criteria should be used to evaluate whether a draft is likely to be successful?

The things I mentioned above should be satisfied. Also, no close reason should apply.

What do reviewers prioritize when evaluating new questions?

I think it is

The overall structure of the question
Does the question make sense?
Is it clear what the author is asking and what technologies they are talking about (if applicable)?
(Maybe) does the title summarize the question?
Do any (typical) close reasons apply?
Everything that has a comment template (though I think the template asking the user to read over the post for minor changes wasn't of much use)

During the betas, I have written my own comment templates for common situations (shameless plug). These are

Questions on Stack Overflow should contain everything necessary to answer them. Please [edit] your question and include the _relevant_ parts of your code using a [code block].
Do you want your question to be published and [post an answer yourself](/help/self-answer) so that future readers can see it or do you want to keep it unpublished?
Please [edit] your question and include that in it. When it gets published, the comments will be cleaned up so all necessary information should be present in the question itself.
It seems like you asked multiple questions in one. Please reduce your post to a single question.
Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem you are trying to solve. It seems like your question is quite broad. When asking questions on Stack Overflow, please ask about _specific_ programming problems or similar. Questions that are too broad are [not considered on-topic on Stack Overflow](/help/on-topic).

While these templates are opinionated, I do think these are cases that often occur. I don't think all of these should necessarily be included in the default canned comments but these are things that (in my opinion) often happened during the betas so it would be good to address them.

How do reviewers decide which questions need improvement?

If anything of the things I mentioned needs to be changed, I would consider the post needing improvement (in the case of duplicates or blatantly off-topic/not about programming/wrong site questions, this would be closing it in the SG and writing a comment), the question needs improvement. If I see any other issues, I can also edit them or ask the OP to do so.

Shameless plug (I feel like I don't want to include that in my answer): I have written two userscripts for reviewing in the Staging Ground. One for viewing other posts of the OP (which was useful for people reposting their SG in the public site) and one for custom comment templates.

"people bypassing the Staging Ground by reposting their question" blargh, I forgot about that "feature" in the beta due to the A-B testing; that is definitely something that needs to have something to stop using doing before the go live if it isn't already.

@ThomA If we don't get that, we might need a bot that automatically reports these kinds of questions to SOBotics or similar.

Depends if there will there be API integration for the SG at launch, I suppose. Otherwise we could end up with a mess like discussions.

I've nominated one of the userscripts for script of the month over on Stack Apps. Go vote for it (and nominate other awesome scripts found on Stack Apps while you're there).

I assume a user's e-mail preferences on the profile will apply/override any review queue-specific preferences. E.g. if I say "no emails at all" on my profile, I won't receive staging ground e-mails.

The big reason why I had always been saying "let's wait and see" about scaling is that SG included plans to include new questions in the new questions listings on the main page, active, tags. So much more of a chance for organically bringing in reviewers than Review Queues, which has zero publicity after the "you earned the privilege" modal. I know that this logic was completed (a year ago) - but can't say for not if it is in this release. Though I hope it is.

Thanks for the shout out. Staging Ground was the best thing that I contributed to at Stack, and I am happy that it has been revived.

@YaakovEllis "include new questions in the new questions listings on the main page, active, tags" that's great to hear, personally that's also been my view (I'd posted an answer requesting it) on getting reviewers for the SG by pushing SG directly on the questions page.

@YaakovEllis With the plans to include questions on the main page, was there much thought/planning about reviewer onboarding (specifically for people seeing the Staging Ground on the main page) because that part seems to be missing?

@dan1st back over a year ago before we paused work on SG, the plan had been to also dedicate more time to reviewer onboarding. IIRC we had early plans for a more compact training module, but was still in the early stages and a post-MVP prod launch thing (we were already feeling AI stuff creeping up on us, and were trying to get as bare-bones as possible MVP out the door, though missed that window in the end). So I know that it was an item on "things that still need to be done" - but current staff can talk better to how that might look in the future.

I saw a question that went through the process and was approved by ONE person with a decent amount of rep (19K+ I think it was?) that was immediately closed by 3 others because it lacked enough details to answer.  Feel like that approver needed a wrist slap as it was clearly NOT a good question as asked.

@MarkSchultheiss You can't assume that an approved question is actually good. In many case, the reviewer doesn't know about it (e.g. because they are not a subject-matter expert) which is fine. Perfect is the enemy of good. But yes, approving is done by a single reviewer (500+ rep) and then it's just like a new question.

@dan1st By chance I happened to note that the approver had, as the second  largest rep tag one specific to the posted question; I then looked for a way to "unapprove" it - which was in effect done by the immediate (in minutes) close votes.

I certainly agree that it's a problem, but, i think it's a problem that should be dealt with using overall trends; if one user is approving more things that end up closed or downvoted than the average they should be made aware of that one way or another.

Which is why there should be a way to access SG information in SEDE.

I prefer not having emails on posts I have reviewed sent to me.  I am on frequently enough that I don't need it.  If I am not on that means I don't have time to process it.  Having them in my SO inbox would be sufficient.

I don't get E-Mails when reviewing so I guess it depends on your E-Mail settings.

Something that was suggested in the closed beta was that users with question bans should be redirected to the Staging Ground (SG) as well. I'm not saying that such users should be able to post as many as they want to the SG (there should still be some kind of rate limit imposed there, perhaps once a month instead, though they can try again sooner if their last post was approved?), however, considering how many users struggle to get out of said bans, having them go through the SG could greatly help them; if they continue to post bad content then those questions aren't ever going to get to the main site so they can't keep digging a deeper and deeper hole.
Although I appreciate this won't be in scope for the initial release, and it does pose additional scaling issues, I would still love to see something like this come to the feature in the future. Hopefully we're see how easily the volume is handled once the launch goes ahead, and then that can be used to work out if it's something we really want in scope for the volume that is both incoming and actively being reviewed.

This concept of using Staging Ground to help people escape question bans has been brought up internally. For now, we've decided that the focus of Staging Ground is on the new user experience, rather than aiding askers who are already question blocked. Because new users' questions comprise such a large volume, making that sustainable needs to come well before we can consider opening the option to existing question-banned users. Once we've made significant progress on long-term sustainability, this may be something we can evaluate - expect it to be a while, though.

That's fine, @Slate . I don't cover it in my answer, I admit, but some of these users that are in said bans are because they didn't have the onboarding they needed during their initial use of the site, so if we will have that feature soon™️then it makes sense to offer it to them too. (Of course, that isn't true for all users that are rate-limited, but if they also want to change their approach, we should welcome it as well.)

Just an idea for an alternative: Instead of allowing users to post in the SG during a question ban, maybe treat them as a new author (meaning their question goes to the SG) when they received a question-bad and can ask a new question again after the question ban was lifted.

The entire Q-ban system could use a redesign, honestly.

Yeah, I don't disagree, @KarlKnechtel . I especially feel that users that frequently produce low quality content, but have high reputation, shouldn't be immune to them. I recall a user in the tags I frequent posting 2-3 questions a day for months; effectively using the site as a support desk. They probably had an average score of -2, almost all closed (and deleted) but weren't banned as they had 10k+ rep due to some well upvotes historic questions (that were probably 10+ years old).

A way I see it working is that deleted questions are effectively disassociated on accounts with a question ban (or close to a question ban) as a one time "turn back the clock" event. If that takes you out of the question ban, you can go to boot camp. uh I mean, the staging ground. The whole point of the boot camp is to prevent people from ending up in a question ban after all (and to spread awareness, of course). So it would be very sour to not grant people who are already banned the opportunity to be enlightened.

@Slate "Because new users' questions comprise such a large volume" <- is this true? How can you tell the difference between new users and new accounts?

@Rob The fraction of users who create multiple accounts to ask questions on Stack Overflow is not a large enough percentage of the whole to meaningfully alter the way I phrased that sentence.

@Slate I'm not after an official retraction; I'm just wondering how you tell the difference between new users and new accounts.

During the test of this there was talk of reputation incentives for those participating in the staging ground, are they being left out for the initial launch? I don't see any mention of incentives in this post or the help center article.

I'd prefer that it launch without them, so that the reputation impact of any such system can be directly known before making a mess of things as opposed to just assuming based on how the system was used during the test.

It says "Improvements to gamification (i.e. badges) and incentivization for reviewers" if "i.e." is used correctly, then there are only going to be badges.

Staging Ground will not be launching with reputation incentives for participation. Broadly speaking, we're going to need to monitor how out-of-balance posts and reviews are before we assess options to draw a wider audience of reviewers towards Staging Ground.

You asked about criteria to use when reviewing.  I suggest reviewing the canned comments proposed at Staging Ground Workflow: Canned Comments.  If the Staging Ground was able to fix every issue that corresponds to one of those canned comments, then that would be enormous progress.  Those canned comments are the result of a lot of work distilling common problems and shortcomings in posts, so I think you could do worse than to make sure at least those issues are easy to detect and bring to the attention of the poster.


Finally, we will be closely monitoring the pace of new questions relative to active reviewers to ensure there is a healthy balance where asker's feel their questions are seen and reviewers aren't feeling overburdened.

OK, that can be monitored but what will happen if there are too many questions/too few reviewers? How will the balance be ensured?

There's an auto publish if a post goes unreviewed for 24/48 (I don't remember) hours. Other than that there's a cap to how many SG posts there can be at a given time (at least there was one in the beta)

@AbdulAzizBarkat I don't think that ensures healthy balance. It just means there is no balance.

Theoretically the throttle they used for the test will still exist as well, limiting the number of questions entering the SG to avoid there being tens of thousands of questions pending after a few weeks. so TLDR, one way or another, some posts will just be posted without review if there aren't enough reviewers.

Only a certain volume of new users' posts will be directed to the Staging Ground. We are in control of that volume, and will try to make sure it doesn't get too far out of balance during the initial release stages. (Posts automatically graduate after some time without review as well, so there's a soft limit to the degree SG can be properly flooded.)

That only some new user posts will be going to the SG isn't highlighted in the Post here, @Slate , it instead states "After creating their question, their [a first-time user's] post automatically enters Staging Ground for feedback and guidance from experienced users before their question is posted publicly." That implies all first-time users to me, not some.

@ThomA Fair enough. Falls under "we forgot to mention that." But hey, that's what answers and comments are for.

Is there a chance to get a staging ground for other sites on the network? Some, like Code Golf and Worldbuilding have hacked together "sandboxes" on their Meta sites, but it is hard to get newcomers to notice and use them, and the "technology" (Meta post which can grow to have thousands of answers, and needs custom sorting to be effective) is not very good. These sites would probably benefit substantially from a properly implemented and integrated staging ground.

AFAIK for now, it's only Stack Overflow but there is an option to extend it to other sites in the future if the company has sufficient interest and the respective community agrees (also I think it's a good idea to wait and see how it works out on Stack Overflow first).

"If the respective community agrees" must be a central criterium. There are sites where I would whole-heartedly welcome this feature, and others where I will be a strict opponent.

Access Criteria
I know that scale is going to be a problem and we will need lots of reviewers, but I still think we need to (at least) re-consider the 500 reputation threshold.
I've seen too many bad reviews done by 2k and up users in the queues. While it might be tolerable in the regular queues, I think it becomes a bit more critical in the Staging Ground. Otherwise the SG simply loses most of its purpose. It's counter-productive, two-fold:

Bad questions might get public to the main site more often.
Askers will not receive, or worse - receive bad feedback on asking questions.

I would suggest trying to come up with better ways to accept reviewers. One option is by review badges - let's say at least a "Reviewer" badge in Triage and/or First Questions.

On a somewhat related note, this is something I suggested in the beta Teams instance regarding keeping the quality of reviews/onboarding. I will quote it here as most people can't access that:

I think we should forget about audits. Instead, I suggest to take those posts that would be an audit and make them into an "introductory course". Similar to the [tour]. Or more accurately, a merge between the tour and an audit. Let's hand-pick some exemplar posts (for good and bad) and use those as a test. Users will be faced with a post and a question "What action would you take here?" and be given the exact same actions of the SG. According to their response they will get feedback and explanations. Not an audit that bans you, but a test to give you an idea of what is expected. This also gives us the freedom to curate and hand-pick the posts to cover all cases instead of relying on a questionable automatic criteria.


I think using anything above 500 is not really an option because of scaling. That being said, I think the real solution to this is proper (Staging Ground reviewer) onboarding. However, I do think other options (like additionally getting SG reviewer access when reaching a certain number of accepted suggested edits) are worth considering.

@dan1st As I said I'm aware of the scaling issue. It's a real problem and was mentioned already in the beta Teams. I just think that the devs need to properly consider the trade-off here - number of reviewers vs. experienced reviewers i.e. quality over quantity. Regarding the onboarding, I believe that in the beta Teams I suggested some kind of interactive tutorial instead of a bunch of text that probably most users ignore. I think Yaakov even liked the idea but not sure if it will happen...

I think this would be https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/staging-ground-testing/a/200/14 (for reference to anybody in the Beta testing team). Yes I do think something about that should absolutely be done (ideally in an interactive way but that would probably be a significant amount of work).

@dan1st Exactly! :) Good catch. It got a status-review at least...

Well we don't know how much status-review means in this case since I don't know about anything ever happening with that one.

Stricter gatekeeping, indeed. I expressed as much in the comments under the main post, good to see you made the effort to write an answer. Reputation is just not a good judge when it comes to selecting people who are should be helping people stranded at sea get to friendlier waters. Before you know it you get the blind leading the blind. I must say that I am unclear about what the staging ground is supposed to teach to people though... will someone who is a die hard old school thou shalt not have a senseth of humors Stack Overflow denizen actually be the right teacher for the SO of tomorrow?

The idea quoted above is one that I was pushing for very strongly (but most likely as a post-launch thing due to the time requirements) while I was still on staff. You get to review with some very minimal participation requirement (maybe like ask one not bad question, or something like that) and then pass the reviewer training (which is not an audit, and you can take until you pass). Low quality reviews/inactivity just mean you have to pass again. I have no idea if it will ever happen, but that was my preferred approach, and I agree, 500 too high (though it was my idea, for pragmatic reasons).

I just edited a post in the second step of reviewing after the OP had added an MRE. Before approving, I edited the post, and both the edit and the edit summary were lost by the system—as a result, I had to fix/edit the post a second time after it had gone through the SG.
I could have told the OP to make the edit themselves, but since they had taken a positive step I decided to edit the post for them to help them out (showing how it's done by example). Also, one of their mistakes was adding a blockquote instead of a source fence, and as usual there's the long-standing bug that the editor doesn't flat remove a blockquote instead quoting it a second time.
Consider fixing the lost edit at least; otherwise you'll be losing all the editing work reviewers may want to contribute. That certainly makes for a frustrating experience.

Also reported here.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I'll leave the answer here as a signpost since others will run into this bug and I didn't see the linked bug report.

Per the answer to the post linked above, this was fixed on July 8.


During the beta, it became clear that many Staging Ground reviews take
significantly more of a reviewer’s time than existing curation
activities across the network. This is still an open question for us,
but we will be working on strategies to address this problem.

Since a reviewer can only comment on such a question and unless a templated comment is used, there's always the possibility the comment itself helps the asker to figure out the solution to the problem, comment back to say thanks and forget all about it.
Happened to me and I was baffled; The asker didn't care to "minor edit" the question as I had suggested. Cognitively, the process has been completed.
I had spent time commenting on a "hidden" question, which effectively got answered but shouldn't be published as it was never edited. It would have been a nice question to be properly answered if published.
You may want to consider that, too.

If you use the Minor Edits option, it means the question is ready to be published and could just use a bit of polishing by the asker.

Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/430467/2745495

What is the conclusion? You feel abused as a blood-and-flesh rubber duck?? And without any artefact for future generations of read-only users. Or something else?

@PeterMortensen Yeah, you feel like an unfulfilled rubber duck, which is, well, scary! :)

The idea would maybe to not be a rubber duck. Staging ground is not about answering a question, it's about making it answerable.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution That tool is called Review queues and it's been there forever.

Already mentioned in comments, but also here as an answer: The scaling problem will likely result in only a very small percentage of new questions getting attention during their stay in the SG. If this is true, then how to distribute reviewers attention within the SG can become an important factor for the usefulness of the feature. I could imagine that attention will be distributed more or less randomly given the long list of new questions every day, but better would be to concentrate on those questions that actually have a chance of becoming good questions afterwards. Not all questions might have equal chances there.
Therefore I advise you to:

Wait a bit and see how the SG develops, measuring a) the percentage of questions getting attention in the SG and b) the improvement of these questions over questions that didn't get attention. I.e. how these questions fare later on (score, answers, close ratio).
See if you can correlate some features (asker rep, asker age on platform, other asker activity like ratio of comments to questions, number of votes given, question length, tags, ...) with the improvement factor.
Use this as preselection criteria for some of the questions that go into the SG. Present them more to reviewers somehow.
Wait a bit more and again collect statistics.
Compare the preselected/highlighted questions in the SG with other questions which also got attention and measure the over-improvement.

If the highlighted (promising) questions get improved even more / fare better afterwards while the non-highlighted keep the original improvement, it was worth it. Otherwise just go back to how it is in the beginning.
