Reviewers should not be required to have asked 2 questions to access to Staging Ground
To access the staging ground, you need to have asked at least 2 questions. This is not stated in the announcement but by kylemit in a comment

you have to have asked at least 2 questions to review

This does not follow the rules for any of the other review queues, and I am sure there are plenty of SMEs with high reputation, have never asked a question and can easily tell if a post would be good or not; they should not be stopped from contributing to the queue.

just go ask two questions, it's ez

Does starting two flamewars in discussions count?

The worse of this is that this is stated nowhere in the original post. That is kind of already addressed by comments in the original post but you have to dig really deep into the comments.

As an aside, the already massive reviewer deficit is likely to be made significantly worse by this decision. This is a net negative towards getting more reviewers, and if anything, biases the SG against moderation-oriented users

To be fair, the Staging Ground is not as simple/quick as other review queues. You're guiding new users on how to ask good questions. It stands to reason you ought to have done the thing you're helping new users with at least once or twice. Though I wouldn't mind if it were reduced down to one unclosed, undeleted question.

@TylerH haven't I seen thousands of questions though? I've gained the experience to know which ones are answerable and which aren't, haven't I? I'm unlikely ever to ask a question and therefore unlikely ever to be able to contribute.

To add to the discussion here, I was one of the beta participants and have asked 0 questions on the site so far. I still have access somehow though.

@RobertLongson "haven't I seen thousands of questions though?" Sure, maybe, but seeing is not the same as doing. I'm not necessarily saying one side is right or wrong, only that there's a very good argument for why helping users craft good questions carries the requirement of having asked a good question yourself. A lot of high rep users answer lots of crappy/off-topic questions, too. Just having seen them and earned rep doesn't mean you can tell what a good question is.

For context, the Staging Ground architecture doesn't currently support someone qualifying as both a reviewer and an asker (and it would be considerable work to make it so). For most users this doesn't matter: most users have either few enough questions to qualify as an asker & <500 rep, or sufficient questions & >500 rep. But in that middle ground, we had to make a decision one way or the other. (There are also some exceptions in the logic here.) It's not impossible to change. I'll bring this up with the team.

As someone who has never asked a question on SO, this seems like a ridiculous requirement. My experience in life is that people really don't understand how to ask until they've spent time answering. You learn a lot about what's needed in a good question by taking the time to answer questions and looking at what's really needed in order to be able to answer. Overall, we really shouldn't care if the person learned what's needed in a good question from asking or answering. We should only care that they actually can give good advice as to what's needed in the question they are reviewing.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I also have not asked any questions. I believe, by virtue of our participation in the Beta, we have been added to a special list that grants access and bypasses any extra requirements.

@Spevacus yes, see this response from staff here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/430404/the-return-of-staging-ground-to-stack-overflow?noredirect=1#comment998943_430404

@Slate Is the Staging Ground ready for someone asking a question in the Staging Ground and becoming a reviewer afterwards? I am specifically thinking about this bug I found during the beta.

@dan1st If it happens again, please re-report it on MSO. Off the top of my head I think this was addressed but I'm not 100% sure

Also related and "annoying" behaviour/workflow (for Users who don't qualify for SG because of this 'Need to have asked 2 Questions' undocumented Req), is that the Direct Link to the SG gives a "Page not found" error, with no explanation... And also, when checking the Timeline of a QT (this one for ex), the "Graduated from staging ground post." entry has a Link which also leads to the same "Page not found" error... Grrr...!

Mini grammatical nitpick about the Title, but "to access to SG" is (grammatically) not correct... Correct are: "to access [the] SG" or "for access to [the] SG" or "to get access to [the] SG"...

@Slate "the Staging Ground architecture doesn't currently support someone qualifying as both a reviewer and an asker" You could have people that would qualify for both choose what they prefer to be. Like if you enter the staging ground it tells you what you are and if you can be both you can change the role.

Oh cool, I did not know that. I will probably never post a question because I am actually pretty good at using Google so I am effectively blocked from being a reviewer for doing my due diligence with old fashioned tenacity. Now that's the stricter gatekeeping I was looking for. Zero points for the actual implementation, but at least it's not just filtering based on reputation points.

@chivracq Yes I've only read a couple thousand of them, cast numerous closure votes on questions which just don't fit the criteria and have pretty much memorized the help center so I can repeat the same doctrine over and over on poorly researched meta posts. What the heck do I know about asking Stack Overflow-compatible questions?

"My experience in life is that people really don't understand how to ask until they've spent time answering" - the problem, though, is that most people who want to ask something, are incapable of providing a useful answer. At best they can look up some of the simplest old questions and provide something completely redundant. More typically it would be redundant except that it introduces wrong information and unclear writing (if it's even proper English).

The requirement for reviewers to have asked two or more successful questions is currently scheduled to be removed. This change will most likely be deployed some time next week.

Thank you Slate; it's great to learn this feedback has been taken on board, well received and that something is changing (that it's promptly is a great added bonus).

You had mentioned that this requirement was for the technical reason that "Staging Ground architecture doesn't currently support someone qualifying as both a reviewer and an asker (and it would be considerable work to make it so)" What, if any, impact will the removal of this requirement have on that aspect for those users who fit in the "middle ground"?

@HenryEcker When someone has >2 successful questions but <500 rep, they will not qualify as either a reviewer or asker. When someone has <2 successful questions but >500 rep, they will qualify as a reviewer.

Hi @Slate, does the status-completed tag mean that the 2 question requirement is now removed? There's a comment here that implies a user with >500 rep doesn't have access.

Never mind, it seems to be working for them now.

Yes, lovely...!, the 'Direct Link' now works, I don't get 404 anymore, but 207 (Questions, ah-ah...!) // Oh..., and from the Right Side-Panel, SG is not just an "Icon", it's a complete Entry in the Menu: "Home" + "Questions" + "Staging Ground" + "Tags"... (And only on 'Main', the 'SG' entry is not present on 'Meta'). From the Announcement, ("click on the “Staging Ground” icon on the left sidebar navigation"), I expected some "loose Icon" somewhere in the Left Navig-Panel... :nerd:
